# innerHTML getting null in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm doing my first typescript project. This function is from a javascript vanilla project I did before, but when I use `react-typescript` I'm getting this error on both `innerHTML` from the function:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```
 function callGames() {
    let bets = document.getElementById('bets-container-lotos');
    bets!.innerHTML = '';
    const games = gamesJson.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < games; i++) {
      bets!.innerHTML +=
        '<Loto id="bets-color-' +
        i +
        '" value="games' +
        i +
        '" OnClick={(' +
        i +
        ') => whichGameIs}>' +
        gamesJson[i].type +
        '</Loto>';
      let changeColor = document.getElementById('bets-color-' + i);
      if (changeColor) {
        changeColor.style.color = gamesJson[i].color;
        changeColor.style.borderColor = gamesJson[i].color;
      } else {
        console.log('Cant find the id bets-color-' + i);
      }
    }
  }

const newBet: React.FC = () => {
 return (
        <LotoContainer id='bets-container-lotos'>
        </LotoContainer>)
}
```

Comment: What guarantees `document.getElementById('bets-container-lotos')` is there by the moment when you call it? `bets!.innerHTML = '';` <- what's the point to cheat and use `!.` here?

Comment: This isn't actually recommended in React, but you can still do it. Another thing that you should remember is that React uses VirtualDOM instead of actually keeping the element in the DOMTree, so it's possible that the element might not have been rendered on screen when you have tried `getElementById`

Comment: zerkms, i know that is not the point of typescript, i did a if(bets) before using ! but im trying to solve that error first

Comment: Samridh Tuladhar, maybe its that. Im doing a React.useEffect(() => {}, [callGames()]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the useref hook instead and do this

```
 <LotoContainer id='bets-container-lotos' ref=bets>
```

And this

```
const bets=useRef(null)
bets.innerHTML=“”
```

Answer (score 1):

Becasue `document.getElementById` can return an element or null. So you need to check `bets` before use it.

```
if(bets){
  bets.innerHTML = '';
}
```